# Merge multiple RDD generated in loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am calling a function in scala which gives an `RDD[(Long,Long,Double)]` as its output.

`def helperfunction(): RDD[(Long, Long, Double)]`

I call this function in loop in another part of the code and I want to merge all the generated RDDs. The loop calling the function looks something like this

```
for (i <- 1 to n){
    val tOp = helperfunction()
    // merge the generated tOp
}
```

What I want to do is something similar to what StringBuilder would do for you in Java when you wanted to merge the strings. I have looked at techniques of merging RDDs, which mostly point to using union function like this

```
RDD1.union(RDD2)
```

But this requires both RDDs to be generated before taking their union. I though of initializing a var RDD1 to accumulate the results outside the for loop but I am not sure how can I initialize a blank RDD of type `[(Long,Long,Double)]`. Also I am starting out with spark, so I am not even sure if this is the most elegant method to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using vars, you can use  functional programming paradigms to achieve what you want :

```
val rdd = (1 to n).map(x => helperFunction()).reduce(_ union _)
```

Also, if you still need to create an empty RDD, you can do it using :

```
val empty = sc.emptyRDD[(long, long, String)]
```

Comment: IIRC you cannot union an RDD to an emptyRDD until Spark 2.0.

Comment: how do you do this if you have to pass the loop index to the helper function ?

Comment: if you want to pass the loop index to the helper function, you can do something like this : 

`val rdd = (1 to n).zipWithIndex.map{ case (x, index) => helperFunction(i) }.reduce(_ union _)`

Of course, in this case it is not necessary as we have an integer incrementing collection but you can replace `(1 to n)` by any collection

Answer (score 2):

You're correct that this might not be the optimal way to do this, but we would need more info on what you're trying to accomplish with generating a new RDD with each call to your helper function.

You could define 1 RDD prior to the loop and assign it a var then run it through your loop. Here's an example:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 100)
val rdd_tuple = rdd.map(x => (x.toLong, (x*10).toLong, x.toDouble))
var new_rdd = rdd_tuple
println("Initial RDD count: " + new_rdd.count())
for (i <- 2 to 4) {
  new_rdd = new_rdd.union(rdd_tuple)
}
println("New count after loop: " + new_rdd.count())
```

Comment: Any body have JavaCode for the same scenario?